# Display statistics from an SVN repository on a web page

Tags: svn, statistics

What is the best way to get statistics for an entire subversion repository and display some of them on a web page? Example. Total number of commits today, this month etc, most active committer etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't worked with it myself but I think [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/index.html) is worth a look. It's Java based.

Features:

> - Timeline for the lines of code
> - Lines of code for each developer
> - Activity by Clock time
> - Authors Activity
> - Author activity per Module
> - Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
> - Stats per directory
> - File count
> - Average file size
> - Largest files
> - Files with most revisions
> - Directory Sizes
> - Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
> - Repository tree with file count and lines of code
> - LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
> - Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days
>
> The current version of StatSVN generates a static suite of HTML documents containing tables and chart images. StatSVN is open source software, released under the terms of the LGPL, based on StatCVS. StatSVN uses JFreeChart to generate charts.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a static HTML file or fragment using a post-commit hook and then link to that file (or include it in a different page).

[More here](http://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101)

Comment: Wouldn't the data available here be related to the individual commit and not the repository as a whole?